# Angular caching returned data from HTTP call not functioning properly

Tags: angularjs

I have this snippet below in my controller:

```
var cache = $cacheFactory('contacts');

var data = cache.get('contacts');

if(!data) {
    Contacts.get()
        .success(function(result) {
            data = result;
            cache.put('contacts', data);
        });
}
```

My `Contacts.get()` call returns 152KB of data and is taking ~1.5s to run.  I'm trying to cache this data since it does not need to be up to date.

However, every time I refresh the HTTP call is still being made and i'm seeing `undefined` in the console from logging `cache.get('contacts')` and `data`.

How can I cache this data returned from the HTTP call and reference it in the scope?

Answer (score 2):

How does your data looks like ? In case it's a json object, just try to stringify it before caching it, something like

```
cache.put('contacts', JSON.stringify(data));
```

---- UPDATE ----

You can't use $cacheFactory to persist data. 
$cacheFactory does not persist over sessions and should only used for in-session persistency, what you're looking for is localStorage. there are a lot of good libraries for easily integrating localStorage with angular (for instance https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Comment: Are you trying to use it in the same session or you try refresh the browser ? $cacheFactory only caches the data for the current session. Have you considered using localStorage instead ? there are great libs for that

Comment: Yes I'm sure, $cacheFactory uses in-memory cache and it should only used for in-session persistency. localStorage should be used for what you want.

Comment: I didn't understand, why should I delete my answer ?

Comment: someone else might have gotten it wrong as well, I think I helped you after all didn't I ?